# sort a matrix according to some group indices in R

Tags: r, plyr

I have a matrix generated as follows:

```
set.seed(999)
mat.a = matrix(round(rnorm(24,4,9)),3,8)
mat.a
```

The `mat.a` looks like this:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]    1    6  -13   -6   12   -8   12   10
[2,]   -8    2   -7   16    6    5  -15    1
[3,]   11   -1   -5    5   13    5   -7    7
```

Now, suppose I would like to sort each row of `mat.a` from smallest to largest, **but according to some group indices**. As you see, there are 8 columns, corresponding to

```
grp.ids = as.factor(c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3))
```

i.e., the first 3 columns are for group 1, the next 3 columns are for group 2, and the last two columns are for group 3. What is desired is to sort **within each group** so that the result is a matrix (call it `mat.b`) like this:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]  -13    1    6   -8   -6   12   10   12
[2,]   -8   -7    2    5    6   16  -15    1
[3,]   -5   -1   11    5    5   13   -7    7
```

Is there a way to efficiently write a function by passing `mat.a` and `grp.ids` to obtain the sorted matrix `mat.b`? Applying some functions in `plyr`? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a function then apply it to each row:

```
sort.vec <- function(x, grp.ids) ave(x, grp.ids, FUN = sort)
t(apply(mat.a, 1, sort.vec, grp.ids))
```

Comment: thanks! this new version seems to be more efficient than the previous one ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
 t( apply(mat.a, 1, function(row) row[order(c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3), row)] ) )
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]  -13    1    6   -8   -6   12   10   12
[2,]   -8   -7    2    5    6   16  -15    1
[3,]   -5   -1   11    5    5   13   -7    7
```

Answer (score 1):

```
matrix(unlist(lapply(split(mat.a, 1:nrow(mat.a)),
                     function(row) tapply(row, grp.ids, sort))),
       nrow = nrow(mat.a), byrow = TRUE)
```